# Laravel 4 - Export non-framework files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've tried to find a simple answer to this question. I might not know how to correctly word this which is probably why I have trouble finding an answer.

Basically, I have an application I have created with Laravel 4 on my localhost. I am just looking for a way to consolidate all of MY files which aren't included in laravel. This way I can just upload ~50 files instead of re-uploading the entire framework when updating my project on my live server.

Thanks

Comment: If you've set up Laravel correctly using `composer`, all the Laravel files should be in `vendor` and needn't be uploaded unless you've done a `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i would see this is to use git deployment, therefore you will only pull in the updated files.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh--net-19564

Answer (score 0):

To not upload every file to your server, you have some options:

1) user composer to update your application, this is the common way:

```
composer update
```

2) Use rsync (for Linux or Mac) to copy files to your server, it copy only changed and new files, so if you changed just one file that's what will be uploaded:

```
rsync --progress -avz -e ssh /var/www/applicationdir user@host:/var/www/applicationdir
```

3) FTP upload. There are some smart FTP applications that only uploads (sync) what changed in one of your ends.

4) Use git to deploy your application:

```
git push // in your development server

git pull // in your live server
```

I have built a package that helps you with git deployment (on Github or Bitbucket). Every time you do a git push, Github will send a request to your server and your application will be automatically updated, check it: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/deeployer